# How to understand ` You can also require a client login with a simple true/false response.`?

Tags: sentence-meaning

When I read this [document](https://developers.whmcs.com/addon-modules/client-area-output/):

> You can also require a client login with a simple true/false response.

How to understand this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that if you specify "true", the client will be required to login, but if you specify "false", that won't be required.

One of the definitions for "require" on a Google search is:

> specify as compulsory

That is how it is being used here.

I do feel the phrasing is a little ambiguous though, with the potential to mean that the client would specify 'true/false' as a way to log in or something like that; I didn't fully understand the sentence until I read the code. It could be written more clearly as:

> You can also make it so that a client is required to log in by setting the 'requirelogin' argument to 'true'.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now.